# ERROR OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_accept SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read client hello A

Tags: ruby, linux, ssl, openssl

Im getting this error while trying to access a https URL.

```
[2016-01-14 14:42:58] ERROR OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_accept SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read client hello A
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/openssl/ssl-internal.rb:174:in `accept'
```

I'm not knowledgeable in this area but looking around and in the rb file I found this:

```
  DEFAULT_PARAMS = {
    :ssl_version => "SSLv23",
    :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER,
    :ciphers => "ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW",
    :options => OpenSSL::SSL::OP_ALL,
  }
```

I tried already to change the ssl_version to TLSv1 and tried to access the URL again but I got the same error...

Additional information:

```
[root@eastapp1 ~]# wget https://10.216.209.65:2224
--2016-01-14 16:21:05--  https://10.216.209.65:2224/
Connecting to 10.216.209.65:2224... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify 10.216.209.65â€™s certificate, issued by â€œ/C=US/ST=MN/L=Minneapolis/O=pcsd/OU=pcsd/CN=eastapp1â€:
Self-signed certificate encountered.
ERROR: certificate common name â€œeastapp1â€ doesn't match requested host name â€œ10.216.209.65â€.
To connect to 10.216.209.65 insecurely, use â€˜--no-check-certificateâ€™.
```

Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: It might help if you add the URL in question. And please improve the formatting of the question.

Comment: You attempted to connect by IP address. Is the IP address listed in the Subject Alt Name of the X509 certificate? Next, please post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname> | openssl x509 -text -noout`. Do so by adding it to your question by clicking *Edit* (and don't post it as a comment).